# R Shiny iframe no longer displaying .pdf source after update?

Tags: r, pdf, iframe, shiny

I've recently updated my packages and my shiny application has a broken iframe that used to display a pdf from the web.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

      headerPanel("PDF VIEWER"),

      mainPanel(
        tags$iframe(style="height:600px; width:100%", src="http://radhome.gsfc.nasa.gov/radhome/papers/GOMAC05_LaBel.pdf"))
      )
  )
```

I've checked this on multiple machines and the fact that it worked previously lead me to believe that the iframe tag is behaving strangely?

Any help is appreciated.

shiny 0.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your referring website is sending a "x-frame-options sameorigin" in the header which basically tells any browser not to allow its content to be displayed in an iframe:

```
library("RCurl")
h = basicHeaderGatherer()
appURL <- "http://radhome.gsfc.nasa.gov/radhome/papers/GOMAC05_LaBel.pdf"
out <- getURL(appURL, headerfunction = h$update)
appHeader <- h$value()
> appHeader[["X-Frame-Options"]]
[1] "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I'll proceed without the iframe, but still confused as to why it worked before.

Comment: Before they were not sending a sameorigin header or you were using an old browser.

Comment: Thanks, I want to upvote, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: It was a good question. You could reverse proxy using something like nginx and send an altered header http://nginx.org/r/proxy_hide_header .